# Query one document or another depending on specific field

Tags: solr

Imagine a SolR-index with documents similar to this

```
[
{
    ProductId: 123,
    Contract: abc
},
{
    ProductId: 123,
    Contract: def
},
{
    ProductId: 123
},
{
    ProductId: 567
},
{
    ProductId: 567,
    Contract: bar
}
]
```

- There is *always* a document with a specific ProductId and without a `Contract`
- Additionally there may be 0 to n documents *with* `Contract`

I need a query, where I can use a `Contract` and that should return me all `ProductId`s *either* the one with the given `Contract`, if exists, or the single document without a `Contract` at all.

For example I will make a query with `Contract: def` (somehow) and it should give me this

```
[
{
    ProductId: 123,
    Contract: def
},
{
    ProductId: 567
}
]
```

- The document with `Contract:abc` is *not* part of the result
- The document with `ProductId:123` but without `Contract` is not part of the result
- The document `ProductId:567` is part of the result, because there is no document with this `ProductId` and `ContractId: def`

In other words what I need is something like

- Give me one documents per `ProductId` and with `Contract:X` XOR `-Contract*`, but not both.

Comment: Could I understand that you want to get two documents one of them has the contract you have searched and the other has not contract and its product does not the product of the first document?

Comment: As I understood, he wants the document with `Contract:X` and all the other documents which don't have a contract or the same id than the document with `Contract:X`.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** Write your query so that records without Contracts as well as all with matching contracts are returned, but the ones with the appropriate contract have the highest score. This gets around the problem that you will sometimes want items in your results that don't match the contract value: `q=Contract:"def" OR (*:* -Contract:[* TO *])`. The `(*:* -Contract:[* TO *])` matches that all records without contracts, and the `Contract:"def"` matches records with the correct contract. The records matching `Contract:"def"` should naturally have a higher score than those with no contract, but if there's any trouble or you just want to be sure, you can add a boost to that clause, `Contract:"def"^2`.

**Step 2** Add [Result Grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping) to the query, configured so that you are requesting only the *highest scoring* record for any given `ProductId`:

```
q=Contract:"def" OR (*:* -Contract:[* TO *])&group=true&group.field=ProductId
```

---

This requires that the `ProductId` field be configured in your `schema.xml` as `multiValued="false"`, as multiValued fields cannot be used as groups. I'm also assuming that you are using the [Standard Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser), either set as a default in your `solrconfig.xml` or by adding the argument `defType=lucene` when you make the query.

The results should look something like this:

```
'grouped'=>{
'ProductId'=>{
  'matches'=>5,
  'groups'=>[{
      'groupValue'=>123,
      'doclist'=>{'numFound'=>3,'start'=>0,'docs'=>[
          {
            'ProductId'=>123,
            'Contract'=>'def'}]
      }},
    {
      'groupValue'=>567,
      'doclist'=>{'numFound'=>2,'start'=>0,'docs'=>[
          {
            'ProductId'=>567}]
      }}]}}}
```

Note that neither the `matches` nor the `numFound` values in the result set will tell you how many groups have been returned, but the argument `rows=XX` can be used to define the maximum number of desired groups (in this case ProductIds).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, we decided to go a completely different way now, so I am not able to tell, whether or not this answer is correct. If somebody else can comment, that it works, I'll be happy to accept it.